# RETROFIT QUERY CONTAINS SPECIAL characters

Tags: android, path, get, retrofit, special-characters

I have special characters in the query path which gives me an error:

> @Path parameter name must match {([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)}. Found:
> metadata.tags.sys.id

My query parameter is :

```kotlin
metadata.tags.sys.id[in]
```

How can I call this parameter in GET Retrofit?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try setting the [Path#encoded](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/69315219bc9068b82a3c320fd6297fed045ece7e/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/http/Path.java#L66) property to `true` in your API call declaration?

Comment: @Jay Not yet. Let me try.